# How to show google ads on click on button click in our site?

Tags: ads, adsense, adsense-api

Can anyone help me to show ads on click on button. I want to load the video ads on click on button from html button like showing on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IMA SDK for HTML](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/) to request video ads. The introduction video on the homepage of their docs shows an ad being played when the user clicks a button, like you're looking for. Once you get started, if you have questions for the IMA SDK specifically, you should reach out on [their forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ima-sdk).